# ionic ion-item option-buttons for swipe not reload the updated buttons

Tags: angularjs, button, reload, swipe, ionic-framework

I have one problem with Ionic framework("version": "1.0.0-beta.1"), when I modify the Item I want to be able to modify the buttons related to the item swipe.
The scenario is : swipe on item, view a list of buttons [open,modify,close].
WHen i Click on Close I want to modify the option-buttons of Item with only the button [reopen].
It is possible in the controller change the option-buttons?
I have tried but the framework not reload the related buttons.
Do you have any hint?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-ion-item-option-buttons-for-swipe-not-reload-the-updated-buttons/2590/5

I have opened a discussion for that in ionic forum.
ANd the solution is come from the new version.

Here is the example of new sintax.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nFmuc